# How to set no border of nested table?

Tags: java, border, itext

I have a table with some cells and nested tables.

Nested tables have border around them but I don't know why.

Cells don't have borders because I add to cell and nested cell:

```
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
```

Then I add nested table into table;

```
table.addCell(nestedTable());
```

It seems like it's the Cell around the nested table that have border.

How to do to set it to zero?

UPDATE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document document = new Document();

    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Table2.pdf"));

        document.open();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

        PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 1"));
        cell1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 2"));
        cell2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 3"));
        cell3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell3.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

        PdfPTable nestedTable = new PdfPTable(2);
        PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Nested Cell 1"));
        cell4.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell4.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        nestedTable.addCell(cell4);

        PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Nested Cell 2"));
        cell5.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell5.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        nestedTable.addCell(cell5);

        table.addCell(cell1);
        table.addCell(cell2);
        table.addCell(cell3);

        table.addCell(nestedTable);
        table.addCell(nestedTable);
        table.addCell(nestedTable);

        document.add(table);

        document.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the code of your `nestedTable()` method?

Comment: UPDATED in question. I also update table.

Comment: Could you put the whole code of `nestedTable()`, and not just snippets, if it's not too long? It's hard to figure out what objects you manipulate and how you manipulate them without a clear global view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I got it.

I cant do this:

```
    table.addCell(nestedTable);
```

instead of this I need to create new cell and inside of this cell add nested table and now I have no border

Answer (score 4):

Try modifying the default cell of your main table:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
```

See the [API](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#getDefaultCell%28%29) for more information.

Comment: Well, it works for me. Are you sure you are looking at the right generated document? Or that you are running the updated code?

Comment: it works, but you have to set the border to the parent table, not the nested table. thanks @AlexisPigeon

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried table.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER); ??

Comment: there is no such method in pdfTable